# Cover switch effect for Mac OS X

Tags: osx

Is there some program for Mac OS that brings same behaviour as cover switch effect for KDE4?

[image: Cover switch effect]

**Note**: This is the behavior I am looking for:

1. I have 3 windows opened at all spaces
2. I press cmd+Tab
3. I'm looking for switcher that will show picture like above (one window at center, one at left side, one at right side)